# Mysterious "Validation failed: Password is too short" in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to seed my production database with a record for the table Users. Here is the model:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Person
  include Contact
  has_many :coworkers, :class_name => 'Coworker'
  has_many :customers, :class_name => 'Customer'
  has_many :locations, :class_name => 'Location'
  has_many :appointment_types, :class_name => 'AppointmentType'
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  #before_create :create_remember_token
  # password
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :create
  # rem_notice_hrs
  validates :rem_notice_hrs, presence: true
  validates :rem_notice_hrs, numericality: true
  # rem_text
  validates :rem_text, presence: true
  # mandatory email:
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  after_initialize :init

  #def create_remember_token
  #  self.remember_token = Account.digest(Account.new_remember_token)
  #end
  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
        BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  private

  def init
    if self.new_record?
      if self.rem_notice_hrs.nil?
        self.rem_notice_hrs = 24
      end
      if self.rem_text.nil?
        if self.company.nil?
          self.rem_text = "Dear [customer title: automatic] [customer family name: automatic], this is a reminder of your appointment with %{title} %{family_name} on [date/time]."
        else
          self.rem_text = "Dear [title] [customer family name], this is a reminder of your appointment with %{company} on [date/time]."
        end
      end
      if self.start_day.nil?
        self.start_day = Time.now
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the seed:

```
    User.create!(first_name:  "Nick",
         email: "user@example.com",
         password:              "user12",
         password_confirmation: "user12",
         phone: 7933336337,
         rem_notice_hrs: 24,
         rem_text: "This is a reminder",
         start_day: "2014-11-21 21:50:16",
)
```

I am running the seed task via capistrano and I am getting:

> ```
> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
> /home/deploy/appmate/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
> /home/deploy/appmate/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
> /home/deploy/appmate/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
> /home/deploy/appmate/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
> ```

What is going wrong here? The password has exactly 6 characters. The validation error should not arise?!

Comment: Can you create a user with the password of length 6 in rails console?

Comment: @JTG: yes - in the development environment on my laptop. I'm now trying to seed the production database. And the code in production has been freshly deployed so it is identical with that on my laptop.

Comment: @JTS: I just seeded the database manually by opening the rails console on my production server. So I solved my problem. But I still have no idea why running the capistrano task causes the validation error.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue in Development and I haven't found a work around.  For now I'm leaving password validation off.

```
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_length_of :password, :within => 4..20
  validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password_required?
```

From localhost:3000/users/new I input newuser@emailaddress.com / password and I received the error:

> 2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
>
> Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters) Password can't be
>   blank